# Using services of a portlet in another Liferay plugin

Tags: liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

We are trying to use the services of a portlet (Portlet A) in another portlet (Portlet B). We have put the jar file of the services (Portlet A) in `\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib` and included this jar in display plugin packages.xml of another portlet (Portlet B).

We are using external database, ie we had made the changes in portlet-spring.xml .

If I deploy the portlet that contains actual services (Portlet A) and call some method of services then it is called fine & it fetches the data. If we write the same method in the another portlet (Portlet B) then it fetches the data.
But the problem occur when we try to write a method in another portlet (Portlet B) that has not been called in the actual service portlet (Portlet A), then the data is not fetched. It always bring a blank.

Can any one suggest what could be the reason.

We cant put up all of the portlets in the same jar as no of portlets are very large.(approx 35).

Or is there any other better solution rather than putting up the jar file in the lib directory?

Comment: i guess your jars should be inside "\tomcat-7.0.27\lib\ext" directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lucky Boy comments, one option is to have your *-service.jar files in the global classpath, `tomcat/lib/ext`

Another option is to explicitly name dependencies: Edit your plugin's `WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` and add a dependency to another plugin that you need for this plugin:

```
required-deployment-contexts=my-other-portlet,my-custom-hook
```

This will make sure that the plugin containing this declaration will only deploy once the dependencies are already deployed, and it will also copy their service-jars into "itself" - e.g. `my-other-portlet-service.jar` and `my-custom-hook-service.jar` will automatically end up in your own webapplication, ready for use.

Comment: Dear Olaf Kock ,
I have tried both of the methods as stated above. But with these I am facing an another problem. I am not able to find the XXXXImpl class in Portlet B.
I need to create an object like XXXX xxxx = new XXXXImpl(); .
Any suggestion on the same.

Comment: Nope, sorry. The *Impl classes are not part of the service interface - service builder has them end up in the plugin's WEB-INF/src folder which is not part of the *-service.jar. This is by design and you should not assume you have access to these classes. You can delegate object creation to your service class though and just have your service return a virgine XXXImpl object (which will most likely end up as XXXWrapper in your dependent project.

Comment: Got it done.. :-)
XXXX xxxx  = XXXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXXXX(-1 or 0)

This would not create a database entry but would return an empty instance which is as good as saying new XXXXImpl() .

If you are having a table with multiple primary key, then create an object of xxxxpk and pass it in the constructor of XXXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXXXX .

Thanks a lot...